# How to hide or spoof bootloader info from any app?

Tags: root-access, bootloader, magisk

I have spent hours trying to perfect build.prop and when I finally was at the end I forgot about this leakage. Any app can easily know device's bootloader info. I realized this when I ran CPU-Z. Installed Magisk and Xposed in systemless mode. Running Lineage OS 14.1. I by no means an expert as it is clearly evident from my question otherwise.

Idea is to hide or fake this information from any app including system apps. But I am failing miserably at achieving this since I have no deep understanding of Android.

I searched Git and XDA but answers were not met with requirement. Final search with keywords "getprop ro.bootloader" shade some light about the fundamental commands about getting this info. I am exhausted right now and I might be not thinking in the right direction so your input matters a lot.

I await your instructions!

Comment: Have you installed and configured Magisk Hide?

Comment: Magisk Hide only hides the Root status. CPU-Z is able to get bootloader info.

Comment: True, but it even says in it's description "Hide Magisk from detections: Google SafetyNet, enterprise / bank system integrity checks, game tamper checks." Other than that, I don't believe what you want is possible without actually relocking the bootloader, but remember that can be detected as well.

Comment: I mean there has to be some way we can know how CPU-Z gets this info from, right? Once we can know that, there is a chance of hiding or faking it. For example how Xprivacy module does it. So what I am looking for is: Either to hide it and shield its original info. Spoof it otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [XprivacyLua](http://repo.xposed.info/module/eu.faircode.xlua) and select `use tracking` Pics below show the difference in output

[image]
[image]

For *spoofing* instead of *hiding* you may have to use custom hooks. You can ask on the [XDA thread of the app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacylua6-0-android-privacy-manager-t3730663/page306) or use the pro version of the module to change values globally or on per app basis

[image]

**Caveat**

Quoting Namnodorel from comments

> Note that this only works if the apps tries to retrieve bootloader status via Java. XPrivacyLua can't do anything if an app uses native code to check the bootloader.

Comment: Note that this only works if the apps tries to retrieve bootloader status via Java. XPrivacyLua can't do anything if an app uses native code to check the bootloader.

Comment: @beeshyams - That did it! (Nowhere on the Internet this question has been answered. I had tried XDA, Reddit and what not!)

Comment: Glad to help. That module is worth it's weight for the  power it has

Comment: Absolutely. I had been a user of previous verions of Xprivacy. Recently had switched to Lua and it is quite empowring indeed. I don't have Pro features right now to test with. Nevertheless, an amazing module!

Comment: I did manage to create a seprate post over there but got no response. So had to go several places to get an answer. Only here I got one.