# How can I Ungoogle my Phone?

Tags: google-play-services

I would like to get rid of everything Google and use open Gapp pico or nano instead.
I have root access
Running Android 7.0 .
There's no working custom ROM for my phone(infinix note 3 pro)

Is there a script or flashable app that can ungoogle my phone ?

Comment: The easiest way would be to install LineageOS for your device. By default it is Google free.

Comment: My infinix note 3 pro doesn't have lineageOS. Custom ROM available is buggy and wouldn't install.

Comment: You can't until you don't stop using Android. However if by un-Google you mean removing proprietary apps developed by Google, make a quick search by: find /*/*app*/ -name com.google.*

Comment: See [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204543/131553). First comment under the question points to a blog that is very detailed and should help you

Comment: You are aware that you're basically asking to get rid of all beef and have cow instead? OpenGApps are just bundeling Google Apps – those apps still remain Google Apps. So what's the sense of "ungoogle" if you just install GApps afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy task if you are familiar with root access and your device is running a custom recovery like TWRP, Philz or CWM.

First you need a full gapps package, this will be ready to be flashed via the recovery and needs to be provided by OGapps.

( The reason it need's to be provided by OGapps is because Open Gapps already has a removal script that will run prior to installing )

The Gapps Installation Log :
- mounting system
- removing old installations
- installing open gapps
- updating system
- unmounting system
- Done !

The above is just a example, but generally what you'll see.   It removes the old google apps first.

Ok, so now you've installed Gapps you'll need to manually remove software that didn't get removed.

This is usually application's that you've updated, even though the SYSTEM has a new APK, the DATA still has an updated application installed, so you'll nees to remove any updates to apps applied from the Play Store previously.

I've never actually had to remove an update from DATA myself, but it's recommended in case of problems... however the OGapps package seems to clean everything up before installing.

P.S
Android is Linux with Java & XML interfaces.

It's conveniently named Android to identify the people that joined these thing's together.

Comment: I will try this.