# Are there ways wherein an app would think it's operating on a different phone?

Tags: root-access, privacy

That means the device ID, and IMEI and every information the app would be able to gather would be what I've pre-set.

It would, for all intents and purposes, be as if it's installed on a different phone and it wouldn't know anything about the phone where it's actually installed in.

Obviously this will require a phone to be rooted, which is the case already.

Answer (score 1):

- [XprivacyLua](http://repo.xposed.info/module/eu.faircode.xlua) an Xposed module can do that. See [How to hide or spoof bootloader info from any app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200052/131553)
  for an example but bear in mind that if the app in question uses Java code , then this module will fail. For a detailed view of module, read [module description](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua/blob/master/README.md). Salient features which you seem to be looking for:

> - Read identifiers (fake build serial number, Android ID, advertising ID, GSF ID)
> - Read network data (hide cell info, Wi-Fi networks, fake Wi-Fi network name)
> - Read telephony data (fake IMEI, MEI, SIM serial number, voicemail number, etc)
> - Read account name (fake name, mostly e-mail address)

- You can also use this Magisk module [MagiskHide Props Config](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magiskhide-props-config-t3789228) in addition to Xprivacy Lua if needed as a supplement . Primary purpose of the module is different and it is less potent compared to Xprivacy Lua because it is a Magisk module and unlike Xprivacy Lua cannot hook into app API's. I haven't used it , instead use Xprivacy Lua